# htaccess Canonical URL and HTTP->HTTPS redirects (custom url)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, canonical-link

I hope so you could help me solve this issue. I am trying to setup my apache server redirects, but without success. I am trying to do this at at once:

1. http://www.example.com -> redirects to -> https:/ /example.com
2. http://example.com -> redirect to -> https:/ /example.com
3. https://www.example.com -> redirect to -> https://example.com
4. (if the URL contains file extensions like .php/.html I want to remove them) LIKE: https:/ /example.com/portfolio.php -> to be replaced to -> https://example.com/portfolio
5. URLs can also contain 1 or 2 URL params and I want to replace the url separated by / like that: https://example.com/portfolio.php?id=1&t=Max -> to be replaced to ->
   https://example.com/portfolio/1/Max

Also all redirects should use R=301 if possible.

Here is what I have so far, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^portfolio/(\d+)/(.*) portfolio.php?id=$1 [QSA,L] 

RewriteRule ^portfolio portfolio.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^about about.php [QSA,L]
```

Please help me solve this issue. It took me so much reading but never did it right. The main problem is that Google Crawlers recognize my pages as duplicated, and I have canonical URL problems which I want to resolve.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Use a VirtualHost https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/vhosts/examples.html. Also, none of what you have included shows you are using an SSL cert. You need to have one (if your SSL is being terminated at the Web Server) and specify the location of the certificate files to use https.

Comment: The SSL cert. is working fine, I have htaccess redirect issues. But, thanks for advice!

Comment: And "it's not working" means _what_ actually?

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but conceptually, this will take care of part of it. Redirect http to https, solving 1, 2, & 3.

File found in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled on Linux

```
Listen 443
Listen 80

IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost*:80>
ServerName www.example.com
redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost*:443>
ServerName www.example.com
redirect / https://example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com

**Put all the other stuff you need here**

</VirtualHost>
```

There are a lot of things to consider, depending on your configuration.

You’ll need to restart Apache after modifying the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^  https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(php|html)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&t=(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/%1/%2 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/(\d+)/(.*)$ /$1.php?id=$2&t=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.html [L]
```

The first three lines after `RewriteEngine on` is to make sure all requests are `https://example....`

The next two lines is to remove both `html & php` extentions.

The next two line capture any query string `/portfolio?id=1&t=max` and rewrite it to `/portfolio/1/Max` externally.

The next two line capture any URI like `/portfolio/1/Max` and rewrite it to original path internally.

The rest of lines are to redirect the rest of URIs and check whether they are `.php or .html` internally.

**Note:** clear browser cache and then test